# Bootstrap - How to keep image centred when browser is shrunk

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

With my Bootstrap 3.0 site I am struggling to keep an image centred when the browser is shrunk. When the screen goes below a certain width the image jumps to the left side of the screen and is no longer centred. My code is:

```css
#sliderScale {
  opacity: 0.6;/* 0.4; */
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /*alpha(opacity=40);*/ /* For IE8 and earlier */
  width:311px;
  max-width:311px;
  padding:0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 } 
#maxCostSlider {
  max-width:304px;
  width:304px;
  padding:0px;
  margin-left:-6px;
 }
 
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
    #maxCostSlider,#sliderScale {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: 260px;
    }
 }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4" style="padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px">
            <img id="sliderScale" src="/assets/img/price slider 1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4" style="margin-top:-44px;padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px">
            <input id="maxCost" data-slider-id='maxCostSlider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The data-slider stays centred correctly but not the sliderScale.

Comment: You can use `margin:auto;` to center items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your #sliderScale css tag:

```
 margin: 0 auto !important;
```

by adding the important, you ensure that nothing can override it.

Comment: Perfect! Does the job beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

This should help, your media query was causing the issue:

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/r1jtef9y/1/)

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
#maxCostSlider,#sliderScale {
    max-width: 100%;
}}
```

Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

when using col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 also add col-sm or xs-(wherever you want it) when the screen shrinks to the SM or XS size it will pick up that code. hope this helps.

Comment: For me adding xs just causes even more problems with centring. Can you suggest exactly what I should use to make it work? I don't understand why the slider widget stays centred but the slider scale image doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.text-center` class or extend style attribute with `text-align: center` on the following div:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 text-center"></div>
```

Comment: That does not make any difference for me the png image still jumps to the left

Comment: It's working for me with the code you have posted. I would say something else is kicking in.